# MacBook Air mid 2011 - Handoff not supported

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

Is there a failure with OS X Yosemite?

I have a MacBook Air mid 2011, with:

- Bluetooth Version 4.3
- Bluetooth Low Energy Supported
- LMP Version 0x6

> Does somebody experience the same behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As of 10/23/2014 The creator of the tutorial below (@dokterdok) has released a [software tool](https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/) to automate the process.**

Below is from the [original macrumors post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=20015070&postcount=609)...

> (@dokterdok)
>
> Update 23.10.2014: I've released a Continuity Activation Tool. No more
>   painful manual hacking. [Link.](https://github.com/dokterdok/Continuity-Activation-Tool/)

---

This is how i fixed it ([according to this wonderful MacRumors Tutorial](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=20015070&postcount=609) mentioned by @Hank):

> 1. Download and install 0xED in your Applications folder, you can get it from here: http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/
> 2. Download and install KextDrop in your Applications folder, you can get it from here: http://www.cindori.org/software/kextdrop/
> 3. Open Terminal and type : `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"`
> 4. Restart your machine.
> 5. Open Finder, type CMD+Shift+G and go to /System/Library/Extensions/
> 6. Copy those two files to your desktop and then delete the originals: `IO80211Family.kext` `IOBluetoothFamily.kext`
> 7. Go to Terminal, and type: `ioreg -l | grep "board-id" | awk -F\" '{print $4}'`
> 8. Your result should look like : Mac-742912EFDBEE19B3, (yours might be different.). Copy it to your clipboard (Select and CMD+C). Don't
>      close terminal yet.
> 9. Open Finder and hit CMD+Shift+G, go to ~/Desktop/IO80211Family.kext/Contents/Plugins/AirPortBrcm4360.kext/Contents/MacOS
>      Note: if you have a different OS language, you might need to replace
>      "Desktop" in the path with your local translation.
> 10. Right Click on AirPortBrcm4360, and choose OPEN WITH: OTHER: 0XED
> 11. Press CMD+F, search for "Mac-" (without the quotes). Make sure the search type is Text and not HEX.
> 12. Look at the first result, for example, it might be Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F
> 13. Go back to the FIND box, in the FIND field enter that first "Mac-" number that you found.
> 14. In the REPLACE field, enter the number you got in Terminal, (remember you left it open.)
> 15. Click REPLACE
> 16. Repeat steps 11 to 15, but this time for the **last** "Mac-" result that you can find in the file.
> 17. Click SAVE
> 18. Open Finder and hit CMD+Shift+G to open the "Go to" popup, and go to ~/Desktop/IOBluetoothFamily.kext/Contents/MacOS
> 19. Right Click on IOBluetoothFamily, and choose OPEN WITH: OTHER: 0XED.
> 20. Press CMD+F.  In the SEARCH field type: `MacBookAir` Click FIND NEXT.
> 21. You will find a block of text containing `'MacBookAir4,1''MacBookAir4,2''Macmini5,1''Macmini5,2''Macmini5,3'`
>       Manually replace the numbers with ones only so they all look like:
>       `'MacBookAir1,1''MacBookAir1,1''Macmini1,1''Macmini1,1''Macmini1,1'`
> 22. Click SAVE (the red circle button) and quit 0xED.
> 23. Open KextDrop, and Drag and drop the IO80211Family.kext that you modified into the window.
> 24. Click INSTALL.
> 25. Repeat steps 23 and 24 but for your modified IOBluetoothFamily.kext
> 26. Go Back to Terminal, and type the following commands. Wait for each one to finish. `sudo kextcache -system-prelinked-kernel` and
>       `sudo kextcache -system-caches`
> 27. Reboot. Make sure you have an Internet connection for the next steps.
>
> Last: SignOut and in again your Mac and iPhone, reboot both.

---

Here is how it should look like after this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Follow this guide, works on the release from yesterday as well, my Macbook Air 2011 is working great.

It's a workaround for sure, and if you are not comfortable with editing kext files... Run!

http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=20015070&postcount=609

Comment: It's okay to include a link in your answer, but the content of the answer needs to stand alone in case the link breaks.

Answer (score 2):

My mid-2011 mb air supports Bluetooth LE and Bluetooth 4, yet apple has prescribed that it shall not support handoff.

The LMP Version required for handoff, 0x6, is also supported.

Why apple decided to not include support for handoff/continuity our mb air models when we have the hardware in place to run it needs further explanation from apple.  [image]

[image]

Comment: It's a shame for Apple... Read the link from the right answer. Everything works fine now. They just didn't include the model from 2011 in their registered files...

Comment: I can confirm it's working, I had the same "Noes" in BT report.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not supported. You can see the system requirements for using Continuity [here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6555):

```
MacBook Air (Mid 2012 and later)
MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 and later)
iMac (Late 2012 and later)
Mac mini (Late 2012 and later)
Mac Pro (Late 2013)
```