# Downgrade Yosemite Release to Mavericks

Tags: macos, downgrade

So I'm considering updating to Yosemite, but I have a 2011, low end MBP, and Im a bit afraid that its going to be slow. If I do upgrade, is there anyway that I can revert back to mavericks? I've seen a bunch of things online, but that was only for the developer previews, which rely on the Mavericks installer still being on the app store, which I don't think it is.

Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin This is the release version. It was possible before to download Mavericks from the app store, but it no longer is.

Comment: If the question is about App Store, you can edit (at least) the subject line; make it distinctive. If you can, don't mix multiple questions where one already has an accepted answer. Incidentally I suspect that we'll soon find an answer about continued availability of Mavericks; certainly there were comparable questions about Mountain Lion after the release of 10.9.

Comment: In MacRumors forums a few minutes ago: [\[SOLVED\] Anywhere to download Mavericks again?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1804536)

Comment: The linked question is not specific to the DPs and the answers include methods for the release. I've edited my answer to include one possible method not mentioned elsewhere but there are numerous answers to that canonical question that covers this in detail. If you believe your question falls outside the scope of that question, feel free to edit your question to clarify. Also, FWIW, the Mavericks installer *is* still on the App Store in your Purchases list for you to re-download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solutions are:

> 1. Create a new partition, and install Yosemite on it. You can try it there, and if you like it, delete the Mavericks partition and increase
>      the Yosemite one
> 2. Make a Time Machine Backup. If you don't like Yosemite, just recover your old system
> 3. You can use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) to do a Backup as well.

I have a 2011 MacBook Air as well. Yosemite is as fast as Mavericks. The only problem is Handoff isn't working out of the box, which i fixed ([see this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150934/macbook-air-mid-2011-handoff-not-supported)).

Comment: Im going to use the time machine thing probably, but Im more interested in the handoff thing. If I have a USB dongle with BT 4.0, will it work with that?

Comment: Probably not. Your MacBook is blacklisted, and it needs to be whitelisted. This is why the tutorial is there.

Comment: I meant if I followed the tutorial, would it work with a dongle instead of replacing the card

Comment: You don't have to replace anything.

Comment: I do If I have a 2011 Mbp

Answer (score 0):

Clone the drive to a completely separate device.
Setup Yosemite on one copy, keep the other to swap back if you don't like it.
Yosemite has been seen to change the drive structure from 'regular' GUID to Core Storage, giving people serious headaches trying to get back to the old setup.

Personally, I wouldn't touch Yosemite yet without this kind of fallback solution.

I know effectively in SE I'm in the doctor's waiting room complaining it's full of sick people - but there have been too many *'oopsies'* in the past week for me to suggest anything less safe.