# Downgrade Yosemite from back-up (not Time Machine)

Tags: macos, restore

I've read some questions and posts regarding Yosemite downgrade from Time Machine back-up (like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151498/downgrade-yosemite-release-to-mavericks) and [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/22/downgrade-os-x-yosemite-to-mavericks/)) but I was wondering if the same thing would work for a bootable backup made with Disk Utility. Will this process work?

1. Boot the Mac from Recovery HD
2. Enter Disk Utility
3. From the restore tab, choose the internal hard drive as destination and the bootable drive as source.
4. Restore

Are there going to be problems due to Yosemite change in drive structure? (as suggested by [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/151501/127411), if I understand it correctly)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Time Machine in this case, use SuperDuper! of Carbon Copy Cloner to make a bootable image on another drive, upgrade, see how it is and if it fails to work, then go boot off the bootable image and clone it back to where it was.

I would suggest taking a Time Machine backup in addition so you always have 2 copies of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, getting a Time Machine backup is surely on my list of things to do. As you guessed I still haven't Yosemite installed and I'm trying to understand exactly how one can revert back before any installation attempt. Your suggestion to proceed in the opposite way (first try Yosemite in an external drive, then if it works clone it back) seems better than my approach, however my doubt is whether the procedure I listed actually enable to restore the backup, without any side effects from the upgrade (seems reasonable that it does, but I want to be sure before trying)

Comment: Furthermore testing Yosemite performances from an external drive wouldn't be biased by the slow USB connection?