# Why can't an iPhone 6 and a mid-2011 MacBook Air see each other in AirDrop?

Tags: macos, ios, airdrop

I'm trying to transfer photos, for example, from an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1.3 to a MacBook Air, mid-2011, running OS X 10.10.2.

In either of these scenarios:

- iPhone set to be discoverable by Everyone
- Finder open to AirDrop on the Mac
- Select a photo on iPhone, select Share, the Mac does not appear in the AirDrop pane

or

- iPhone set to be discoverable by Everyone
- Pick a photo on the Mac, select Share, Airdrop, no devices appear in the Send via AirDrop dialog

I have successfully used AirDrop from this Mac to other Macs in the past. Any idea why it isn't working with my iPhone? (I should point out that other features of Yosemite, such as receiving phone calls and SMS from the iPhone on the Mac, are functioning properly.)

Comment: Blutooth & Wifi both on, on both devices? Within 30ft?

Comment: on my iphone 6plus and mbp early 2011 I have the same problem, they don't see each other.

Comment: please see this question and answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150934/macbook-air-mid-2011-handoff-not-supported

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mac (and mine too) is not compatible with airdrop between mac and iOS

**System Requirements**
To see if your Mac works with AirDrop, make sure you’re in the Finder by clicking the desktop (the background area of your screen), or by clicking the Finder icon in the Dock.
 Then, check to see if AirDrop is listed as an option in the Go menu.
 If you don't see AirDrop listed, your Mac doesn't support this feature.
In order to transfer files between a Mac and and an iPhone, iPad or iPod touch

- your iOS device needs to include a lightning connector
- your iOS device needs iOS 7 or later installed
- **your Mac needs to be a 2012 or later model with OS X Yosemite
  installed**
- Your Mac and iOS device both need bluetooth and Wi-Fi turned on. You
  do not have to be connected to a specific Wi-Fi network

*source:*
http://support.apple.com/en-is/HT203106

Answer (score -2):

Uncommon but valuable answer:

Your iPhone and Mac *must* be on the same wireless network. I run into this fairly often in urban workspaces, shops, and homes.

Comment: This is incorrect. "Your Mac and iOS device both need bluetooth and Wi-Fi turned on. You do not have to be connected to a specific Wi-Fi network. "